# What is the best way to handle foreign keys with using type/subtype data model?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys

I have to create a database structure for a (limited) set of products with some common and a lot of different attributes. I have created a main `Product` table/type, and for each subtype (`Car`, `Bike`) created a separate table. There is a foreign key reference of the `product` with unique constraint (one to one relation) in every subtype with also serves as a primary key in the subtype.

I have to refer products in other tables in a way that the target table can contain any one of the product types. For example, there is a contract table with the product as a foreign key in it. It can be any of subtype, (`Car`, `Bike` etc). How should I model these foreign keys?

I have two solutions in mind. I can create a reference in the contract table without FK constraint and also add another field to save to the subtype of the product (Polymorphic association). But I have to reference the product in a lot of places. I am afraid this approach will create an unmaintainable mess when used extensively.

The second solution is that I just reference the product supertype in every relationship and access subtype attributes from supertype because there will be one and only one subtype record for every supertype record.

I want to know how manageable is the second approach in the long run? What is the best way to join tables when I also need to fetch attributes of subtype while querying the product table?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the second approach and create a foreign key to the `product` table wherever you need to reference "products" in general (not a specific product type).

If you do need the additional sub-type specific attributes when querying e.g. the `contract` table, you can always join to the sub-type tables or retrieve the additional attributes in a separate query. This depends on how often you need the specific attributes in the context where you just need "a product".

Depending on the requirements you have on the product specific attributes you might want to consider ditching the sub-type tables altogether and store the type specific attributes in a `jsonb` column in the `product` table. If you have really strong requirements with regards to data type checking or a fixed (and controlled) set of additional attributes, then this won't obviously work.

Answer (score 0):

Questions like this one get asked from time to time, although usually the subtypes are particular to the case at hand.

You can view my usual answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193394/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-have-several-mutually-exclusive-one-to-one-relationships/193401#193401)
noting that the term I used was superclass/subclass.

Your approach resembles Class Table Inheritance.

One technique that is worth a glance is Shared Primary Key.  The subclasses don't have their own Id field.  Instead, they use a copy of the Id  field of the superclass table.  This copy can function as a foreign key back to the superclass table and also ass the primary key of the subclass table.  This makes some of the joins simple, easy, and fast.